# Accessing a Generic handler (.ashx) via Https protocol through AJAX from a page which is in Http protocol leads to unsuccessful login

Tags: asp.net, http, https, forms-authentication, httphandler

we have a site in which few pages travels in https and few in http and we have implemented a Generic http handler(ashx) for login and auth.

We are using Forms authentication in our site and manually setting Auth cookie in Handler
We have set the access-control-allow-origin to support the mixed of http and  https

For security needs we tried to access the handler in https protocol and facing the below issue

1. When the handler (https) is getting called through AJAX from the secure page (https) everything is working fine
2. But when the same handler (https) is getting called thorugh AJAX from the non secure page (http) it is not working as in previous case.

In the AJAX success call we are just refreshing the page in javascript. 
In 1st case the user name is coming 
In 2nd case the same login link will be there.

I am not sure of what is the problem here ? and don't know where to look out ?

Kindly help me out

Thanks

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    string Message = "";
    try
    {
        string EmailId = HttpContext.Current.Request["emailid"].ToString();
        string Password = HttpContext.Current.Request["Password"].ToString();

        string User = "";

        Entities.UserTable user = null;
        UserDAL userDAL = new UserDAL();
        user = userDAL.UserLogin(EmailId, Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            int userId = user.Id;

            string roles = "User";
            bool rememberUserName = true;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1, // Ticket version
                user.Id.ToString(),// Username to be associated with this ticket
                DateTime.Now, // Date/time ticket was issued
                DateTime.Now.AddYears(20), // Date and time the cookie will expire
                rememberUserName, // if user has chcked rememebr me then create persistent cookie
                roles, // store the user data, in this case roles of the user
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath); // Cookie path specified in the web.config file in <Forms> tag if any.

            string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies); // Hashed ticket
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(20);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            Message = "success";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "Please check your Mailid or password.";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Message = "Please contact Support";
    }

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(Message);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get in your browser console?

Comment: i am not getting any error in the console as well as i am getting success msg in the AJAX response.

Comment: Your problem is most likely somewhere else then! Check if your cookie is set properly and sent on further http AND https request. Are you using the "secure" flag when you set the cookie (if you are, remove it and test again)?

Comment: Actually i have had a same thought cookie could be the problem and i have tried setting isSecure flag = false and still the same result, but then a question raised in my mind if cookie was the problem then how come  the same cookie set in https page works in http page with out any problem.

Comment: You will need to show some code if you want further help :)

Comment: Are you aware that sending login/password in https from an HTTP page do NOT protect them ? the login page MUST be https and the session cookie MUST have the 'secure' flag to be send only with encrypted (https) webpage.

Comment: Have posted pseudo code here guys, am i doing something wrong here